# Integration questions when migrate monolithic to microservices using Quarkus

Tags: migration, microservices, monolithic

Currently I have a monolithic application with some modules like financial and accounting. This application uses a single database and the modules are divided into schemas, so when I need to display the data on user interface or in a report I just need to do a simple query with a couple joins.

My question is, in a microservices structure where each module has his own database, how do I retrieve this data getting the same result as if I were in a single database?

Answer (score 0):

When talking about splitting the database in the process of migrating a monolith to Microservices, there are some known patterns like:

- The shared database
- Database view
- Database wrapping service
- Database as a service

Seems the database view or the database as a service could be a candidate in this case, but of course no one better than you can decide which one is viable in your project.

I highly recommend you to have a look at chapter 4 of "[Monolith to Microservices](https://samnewman.io/books/monolith-to-microservices/)" by Sam Newman.